# Manage Keyboard Shortcut Conflicts in Linux (KDE, Gnome, POPOS...)

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, gnome, kde, elementaryos

If I have a program that needs a specific shortcut, I cannot use this shortcut unless I disable the system wide shortcut. so if I want to press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> and I have a shortcut to open task manager using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>ESC</kbd>, the first shortcut will not work unless i turn the second off (unmap it).

This is not a single Desktop issue, it is same across almost all that I tried. is there a way that makes system not take action if i pressed the shortcut within a certain program just like in Windows? Is there any tested DE that solves this issue?